# Asignar variable sin referenciar

Tags: angular, typescript

¿Cómo puedo asignar una variable sin referenciarla en typescript?

```
let miObjeto:Object = res; //Respuesta de función de API que me devuelve un objeto cualquiera.
miObjeto.cantidad = 2;
let auxObjeto:Object = miObjeto;
miObjeto.cantidad = 5;
console.log(auxObjeto.cantidad) // Devuelve 5 referenciando el cambio de miObjeto en vez de 2.
```

Comment: Justo igual que en JavaScript, puedes usar `let auxObjeto:Object = { ...miObjeto };`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes usar la [sintaxis de propagación (*spread syntax* en inglés, *sintaxis extendida* en la traducción de MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) para conseguir una copia independiente del objeto:

```
let auxObjeto:Object = { ...miObjeto };
```

Te dejo un ejemplo en línea en la siguiente URL:

- https://codesandbox.io/s/silent-wind-s4evx?file=/src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: No estoy consiguiendo que me funcione de la forma en la que me indicas, tal vez haya algo mal en mi ejemplo, pero al intentar usar la sintaxis de propagación me da errores. Lo he conseguido solucionar parseando y desparseando con JSON como indico en mi respuesta, de todas formas intentaré revisarlo de nuevo cuando tenga algo más de tiempo. Gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir el código exacto? ¿Qué versión de Angular.io usas? Como puedes ver, he usado tu código exacto y con este método funciona sin problemas: [https://codesandbox.io/s/icy-pine-xxj18?file=/src/app/app.component.ts:445-937](https://codesandbox.io/s/icy-pine-xxj18?file=/src/app/app.component.ts:445-937).

Comment: Como puedes ver en la documentación oficial, este operador está disponible desde TypeScript 2.1 (finales de 2016, hace 5 años): [https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#object-spread-and-rest](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#object-spread-and-rest). La versión actual de TypeScript es la 4.4 (aunque ya está en beta la 4.5).

Comment: No puedo compartir mi código exacto, pero he visto como funciona y tras comprobarlo por mi cuenta de forma independiente he visto que funciona correctamente. Gracias :)

Answer (score 1):

Finalmente he conseguido solucionarlo usando JSON de la siguiente manera.

```
let auxObjeto = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(miObjeto));
```

Comment: No creo que sea la mejor solución, pero es lo que a mí me ha funcionado en  mi caso particular.

Answer (score 1):

La solucion que mencionas

```
let auxObjeto = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(miObjeto))
```

puede dar errores segun el caso

```
JSON.stringify({ key: Nan });
JSON.stringify({ key: Infinity });// lo convierte



en "{"key": null}"
```

y problemas con

```
Date() --->es parseada como Strings
```

puedes usar  Lodash